# What does getstatic really mean in bytecode?

Tags: java, bytecode

I have this byte code:

```
new                 java.lang.Object
// stack is [newObjectRef]
dup 
// Stack is [newObjectRef newObjectRef]
invokespecial       void java.lang.Object.<init>()
// Stack is [initializedAsTypeObjectObjectRef]
putstatic           java.lang.Object class.a
// variable a has the reference of new object
getstatic           java.io.PrintStream java.lang.System.out
// Take the static value of System.out
// Stack is [initializedAsTypeObjectObjectRef System.out]
```

Update this is the continuation:

```
> ldc                 "test" // Stack is
> [initializedAsTypeObjectObjectRef System.out "test"]
> jsr                  pos.0000026C // call a subrutine invokevirtual       void
> java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.String) // actually print the
> result // stack is (I think) Empty at this time ?
```

Does the translation is:

```
  Object a = new Object();
  a = "test";
  System.out.print(a);
```

Is my stack good ?

I am not sure to well understand out().
Probably I will have to use out() setter and to print() after ?

I always use out() to print habitually..

Comment: getstatic loads the value of a static class variable on the stack. What do you want to know?

Comment: I my operand stack is actually good ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I compile the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object a;
    a = "test";
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

and run

```
javap -c Main
```

I see

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code:
   0: ldc           #2                  // String test
   2: astore_1      
   3: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   6: aload_1       
   7: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
  10: return
```

You can see that `getstatic` loads the field `System.out`

---

Object doesn't have a `method` called `out()` so I don't believe you are looking at the code you believe you are.

`getstatic` gets a `static` fields e.g. `System.out` is a `static` field of System so if you write

```
System.out.println();
```

This will result in a use of `getstatic`

Comment: your write, it's for System.out object.

So it get out object, but not actually print ?

Comment: I would take out the `= new Object();` as its redundant and confusing.

Comment: Thank you, it was actually exactly was I was looking for. My last question: after the println() function, is the stack empty or it does not touch to the stack ? Cause, the next opcode is a return (its actually in a function), so it must return the object reference..

Comment: `return` returns nothing. It is used for method which have a `void` type. The are other byte code instructions like `ireturn` and `areturn` to return values. The method `java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V` has a return type of `void` (you can see from the `V` at the end) and so it returns nothing as well.

Comment: Okay, it looks stupid, but actually just return type are stack in the operand stack ? Because a void does not return anything, there is not value in the stack ?

Comment: Does opcodes like "invokespecial void java.lang.String.<init>(char[])" push value in the operand stack, if its a void return.. ?

Comment: When `return` is used there cannot be anything on the methods stack (you will get a verity error otherwise)

Comment: @Pier-alexandreBouchard That method doesn't return anything either. Its the constructor for `String(char[])`

Comment: The return value is added to the callers stack (there can only be 0 or 1 return value)

Comment: it can be also the reference to the return object, or 0 or 1 are for constructors ?

Comment: methods can return 0 or 1 values. Constructors and static initialisers are always `void` and never return anything.

Comment: So, where are stored returns values that caller "call". I mean, reference must be stored somewhere ?

Comment: return values are pushed on to the stack.

Comment: to the caller stack.. That's what I tought! Thank you!

Comment: The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546124/what-does-getstatic-really-mean-in-bytecode#comment10589090_8546173) “*When return is used there cannot be anything on the methods stack (you will get a verity error otherwise)*” is wrong. There can be anything you want on the operand stack. It will just be ignored. Likewise, there can be an arbitrary amount of values of any type on the stack for the value returning instructions, as long as the topmost value has the right type.